# Sent Outlook mails not in additional mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Having trouble to get sent emails to the correct mail account here is the setup:

- Outlook 2013 Client on Terminal Server 2008R2 (Exchange 2010)
- Primary mailbox x@x.com
- Additional mailbox y@x.com added as additional mailbox in the same profile
- When user sends email with the y@x.com, the sent items are send to the x@x.com mailbox
- Not possible to use separate Outlook profiles or additional exchange account in active profile because of company policies.

Already checked the following but this doesn't seem to solve the problem:

[Link 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2632409/messages-that-are-sent-by-using-the-send-as-and-send-on-behalf-permissions-are-copied-only-to-the-sent-items-folder-of-the-sender-in-an-exchange-server-2010-environment)

-> doesn't seem to make a difference

[Link 2](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/278)

-> mails stuck in outbox after applying fix

Answer (score 0):

Remove y@x.com from additional mailboxes and add it as an additional Exchange account.

Comment: OP states "•Not possible to use separate Outlook profiles or additional exchange account in active profile because of company policies."